# How to prove the existence of non-abelian group of order $125$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

The following question was part of my algebra assignment.

> Let $G$ be a non abelian group. Can its order be $125 ?$

$p$ groups have non-trivial center. So, if $|Z(G)| =125$ and the group is abelian, if $|Z(G)| =25$ then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic  and the group is abelian.But if $|Z(G)|= 5$ then G/Z(G) can be $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$  but how to prove that group is non-abelian in this case?

Any other approach of proving it non-abelian is also welcome.

Comment: If $|Z(G)|=5$ then the center is $\mathbb{Z}_5$; did you mean $G/Z(G)$ can be (in fact, **will be**) $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: See https://bit.ly/35ThsQ9 (this downloads a paper by Keith Conrad on groups of order $p^3$).

Comment: Actually $|Z(G)|=25$ is impossible (it would imply $G$ is abelian, but that in turn would imply $|Z(G)|=125$, a contradiction). Indeed if $|Z(G)|=5$, then $G$ cannot be abelian for the same reason! The only issue is actually finding a $G$ for which $|Z(G)|=5$ (and hence $G/Z(G)\cong\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_5$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ya! I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Heisenberg group  modulo $5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p) is a non-abelian group of order $125$.

It is the set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb F_5$ of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & a & c\\
 0 & 1 & b\\
 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$